# "Saldo e importo": what is the difference?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, word-choice, difference, single-words

What is the difference between the words *saldo* and *importo*? Aren't both just amounts that need to get paid? It seems like in Italian it is not enough to say *quantità* to refer to an amount when dealing with money. It seems like *saldo* is a balance whereas *importo* is an amount to be deposited. Is this the difference? Where can I find a dictionary of banking and business terms in Italian? Italian to English or Italian to Italian will do.

Comment: Since IT-IT is ok for you, you may start here: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/saldo2 and http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/importo . It's a general-purpose vocabulary, but a quite good one.

Comment: Not only “in Italian it is not enough to say _quantità_ to refer to an amount when dealing with money”, but you never say that when talking about money: you'd say _importo_, _somma_, _cifra_ etc., or more specific terms if you are mentioning prices, fees, payments and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the difference, correct.

If it helps further, you can picture *saldo* as referring to what is "left to conclude the business", so for example the resulting balance of the positive and negative accounting transactions, the amount due in an invoice, or the remaining inventory that needs to be sold out in a shop (that's why we advertise discounted sales as *saldi*). Similarly, *importo* is a quantity of value that needs to be "brought", in the pockets of the seller for example.

As to your other question, you can try these out:

- https://www.agenziaentrate.gov.it/wps/portal/english/glossary
- http://www.andreabecca.it/lettera_a.html
- https://is.muni.cz/el/1456/jaro2015/XPX_IUDA/um/GLOSSARIO_english_italian.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!